# synch between gazebo and rviz

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i have a question about the synchronisation between gazebo and rviz:
i have set up a world in gazebo with lots of obstacles but my rviz doesn't "see" any of them. i really don't know how to fix this.

thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41580/synch-between-gazebo-and-rviz/) by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on 2012-08-16**:
oh, that sounds logical. and how can i make the robot perceive the gazebo-world?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-16**:
Use some simulated sensor, such as a laser range finder or kinect.

**Comment by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on 2012-08-16**:
i have a sick_s300 sensor on my simulated robot but it still doesn't work. and is it normal that the laser scan moves in the rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo and Rviz are two different things.

Gazebo displays/provides the simulated "real" world. Rviz only displays what the robot sees (and any other program outputs to rviz). So as long as there is no data from the robot somehow perceiving the world, rviz won't show anything.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4